# needing to get count of the array in dictionary for my CollectionView

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, count, uicollectionview

Ok, I'm trying to make my CollectionView with each section having a title and within each section is 3 imageviews with their corresponding label. I have the image views matched up to the labels, but I'm having a problem being able to return the proper numberOfItemsInSection. 
I've changed my code so many times in an attempt to fix this, I'm not even sure what is right within the rest of my app, but in essence this is the important part:

```
var sectionsArrayDictionary : [String:Array<String>] = ["level 1" : ["item1", "item2", "item3"], "level 2" : ["item4","item5", "item6"], "level 3" : ["item7", "item8", "item9"]]
```

I can not figure out a way to access the values so that I can return a count.
(And as an extra help if anyone knows how to fix: my pictures are showing the same 3 images in each section, instead of each section showing its own pictures. I'm hoping this will resolve when the above part gets fixed.)

update:
my code is a mess, but since you would like more code here it is. There are two different tutorials combined at the moment, so it may confuse you more.

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "collCell"
let headerViewIdentifier = "headerView"
var sections: [Section] = SectionsData().getSectionsFromData()

class LayoutController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)
    var animalLabels = ["max", "roxy", "buster", "daisy", "charlie", "maggie", "buddy", "ruby", "lucky", "bella"]
    var animalImages = ["max", "roxy", "buster", "daisy", "charlie", "maggie", "buddy", "ruby", "lucky", "bella"]


    var section1 = ["max", "roxy", "buster"]
    var section2 = ["daisy","charlie", "maggie"]
    var section3 = ["buddy", "ruby", "lucky"]
    let sections: [String] = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]
    let s1Data: [String] = [item1, item2, item3]
    let s2Data: [String] = [item4, item5, item6]
    let s3Data: [String] = [item7, item8, item9]
    var sectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:]




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sectionData = [0:s1Data, 1:s2Data, 2:s3Data]
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let imgName = indexPath.row
        cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: self.animalImages[imgName])
        cell.animalLabel.text = self.animalLabels[imgName]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return sectionInsets
    }


    //I don't think this is doing anything...tried to convert it from tableView code
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView: Header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerViewIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Header

        headerView.headerLabel.text = "Level"

        return headerView

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print(segue.identifier)
        print(sender)
        if(segue.identifier == "detail"){
            let cell = sender as! CollectionViewCell
            let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

            let imgName = animalImages[indexPath!.row]



            print(vc)
            vc.currImage = UIImage(named: imgName)
            vc.textHeading = animalLabels[indexPath!.row]
            //
            //            vc.heading.text = self.titles[0]
            //            vc.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imgName)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get rid of the sectionData (which has the block of code right above it with let sections, let s1data, and var sections). It is not helping at all.
I am trying to replace it instead with

```
class SectionsData {

func getSectionsFromData() -> [Section] {

    // you could replace the contents of this function with an HTTP GET, a database fetch request,
    // or anything you like, as long as you return an array of Sections this program will
    // function the same way.

    var sectionsArray = [Section]()

    let level1 = Section(title: "Level 1", objects: ["max", "roxy", "buster"])
    let level2 = Section(title: "Level 2", objects: ["daisy","charlie", "maggie"])
    let level3 = Section(title: "Level 3", objects: ["buddy", "ruby", "lucky"])


    sectionsArray.append(level1)
    sectionsArray.append(level2)
    sectionsArray.append(level3)

    return sectionsArray
}
```

}

and 
    struct Section {

```
    var heading : String
    var items : [String]

    init(title: String, objects : [String]) {

        heading = title
        items = objects

    }
}
```

unfortunately I can't call the heading, items, title, or object as a member on the main view page... so I'm stuck at the moment

Comment: Please show your code. We cannot fix any code without seeing it.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 7/Swift 2?

Comment: xcode7 yes, and honestly I don't know what version of swift

Comment: Xcode 7 comes with Swift 2.x, and Swift has changed in many ways since 2 to 3. I recommend you to update your Xcode to the latest and find tutorials or sample codes fit for the updated Xcode. You may need to upgrade your macOS, but you can get both Xcode and macOS upgrade for free. (You just need enough disk space to upgrade.) Though it may take some time,so I'll try to write an answer in Swift 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, how to get count from the Dictionary:

```
var sectionsArrayDictionary : [String:Array<String>] = ["level 1" : ["item1", "item2", "item3"], "level 2" : ["item4","item5", "item6"], "level 3" : ["item7", "item8", "item9"]]

let sectionIndex = 0
let sectionName = "level \(sectionIndex+1)" //->level 1
if let sectionItems = sectionsArrayDictionary[sectionName] {
    let count = sectionItems.count
    print(count)
} else {
    print("No entry for '\(sectionName)'")
}
```

Some points:

- in actual code, the key would be given as an integer index starting with 0, the code above includes converting the integer to the String key of the Dictionary
- in Swift, the return type of subscript (`[]`) to Dictionary is Optional, the code above is using Optional Binding to work with it
- in the `true` code-block above, `sectionItems` is just an `Array<String>`, so you just use `count` property to get the count

But all above may not be needed when you adopt your new `SectionsData`.

---

Before adapting your code to this new `SectionsData`, a little modification:

```
struct Item {
    var imageName: String
    var labelText: String
}

struct Section {

    var heading : String
    var items : [Item]

    init(title: String, objects : [String]) {

        heading = title
        items = objects.map {Item(imageName: $0, labelText: $0)}

    }
}
```

In your code, you treat the label text and the image name of each item separately, so introduced `Item` type to hold them separately.

---

`Data` is used too often in apps, so I renamed it `SectionsManager`. Also creating an instance at each usage is not recommended, *Singleton pattern* is a preferred way these days.

```
class SectionsManager {

    //### Singleton
    static let shared = SectionsManager()
    private init() {}

    func getSectionsFromData() -> [Section] {

        // you could replace the contents of this function with an HTTP GET, a database fetch request,
        // or anything you like, as long as you return an array of Sections this program will
        // function the same way.

        var sectionsArray = [Section]()

        let level1 = Section(title: "Level 1", objects: ["max", "roxy", "buster"])
        let level2 = Section(title: "Level 2", objects: ["daisy","charlie", "maggie"])
        let level3 = Section(title: "Level 3", objects: ["buddy", "ruby", "lucky"])


        sectionsArray.append(level1)
        sectionsArray.append(level2)
        sectionsArray.append(level3)

        return sectionsArray
    }

    func getSectionsFromDictionary(dictionary: [String: [String]]) -> [Section] {
        var sectionsArray = [Section]()

        //###  `.sort({$0.0 < $1.0})` sorts the dictionary by its key.
        for (title, objects) in dictionary.sort({$0.0 < $1.0}) {
            //print(title, objects) //See what is happening while debugging.
            let level = Section(title: title, objects: objects)

            sectionsArray.append(level)
        }

        return sectionsArray
    }
}
```

I also added a method to create an `Array<Section>` from your `sectionsArrayDictionary`.

---

With all above preparation, your `LayoutController` would become something like this:

```
class LayoutController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var sectionsArrayDictionary : [String: [String]] = ["level 1" : ["item1", "item2", "item3"], "level 2" : ["item4","item5", "item6"], "level 3" : ["item7", "item8", "item9"]]

    let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)

    //### With using an Array of Section, your code gets simplified.
    var sections: [Section] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //### Choose any one you prefer.
        //sections = SectionsManager.shared.getSectionsFromData()
        sections = SectionsManager.shared.getSectionsFromDictionary(sectionsArrayDictionary)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //### Return the number of items in the specified section.
        return sections[section].items.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        //### Your old code does not use `indexPath.section`, so all sections show the same contents.
        let sectionIndex = indexPath.section
        let itemIndex = indexPath.row
        let item = sections[sectionIndex].items[itemIndex]
        cell.animalImage.image = UIImage(named: item.imageName)
        cell.animalLabel.text = item.labelText
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> String? {
        //### Try this.
        return sections[section].heading
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        //### Not sure what you really want to do here, so keeping it as is.

        let headerView: Header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerViewIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Header

        headerView.headerLabel.text = "Level"

        return headerView

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print(segue.identifier)
        print(sender)
        if(segue.identifier == "detail"){
            let cell = sender as! CollectionViewCell
            //### Do nothing when `indexPath` cannot be gotten.
            guard let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell) else {return}
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

            //### You can retrieve the item in the same way as `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`.
            let sectionIndex = indexPath.section
            let itemIndex = indexPath.row
            let item = sections[sectionIndex].items[itemIndex]
            let imgName = item.imageName

            print(vc)
            vc.currImage = UIImage(named: imgName)
            vc.textHeading = item.labelText
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

You may need some fixes to make this code work in your project, but I hope its not too many and you can do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, my code is no longer showing errors and my collectionView is displaying the correct pictures now on the first page :)

Comment: Happy to hear that. Hoping your further development will go without problems. But if you find something difficult, I would be glad to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Given a section string.

```
let count = sectionsArrayDictionary["level 1"].count
```

I know there must be more to it, so you need to post more code for us to understand the problem better.

**UPDATE:**
So we are still missing the key declaration of `Section` but assuming you can access its `objects` property directly; this is what you need.

```
let count = sections[1].objects.count
```

The count variable should now be 3 for the level two objects daisy, charlie, and maggie. Going forward, you should only develop for Swift 3 and soon 4. Don't switch midstream in this project but **nobody** is developing with Swift 2. Any online Swift 2 tutorials are out of date. Good luck.

Comment: "use of unresolved identifier" if I do that . thank you though. I posted more code to help

Answer (score 0):

here using this get total number of arrays in your sectionArrayDictionary

```
var sectionsArrayDictionary : [String:Array<String>] = ["level 1" : ["item1", "item2", "item3"], "level 2" : ["item4","item5", "item6"], "level 3" : ["item7", "item8", "item9"]]

var keys = Array(sectionsArrayDictionary.keys)
print(keys)

print(keys.count) //Output - 3
```